# Creating Shared OneNote Notebook for My Company

Tags: file-sharing, microsoft-onenote, cloud, collaboration

I'm working as a web developer contractor. Unfortunately I have found very little documentation in my new role.

Is there any way to create a shared Microsoft OneNote Notebook so that my teammates and I could use it for documentation? If yes what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Hopefully you saw the same as in  the screenshots I added recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can choose to share notes with people you select and work together with them at any time, even if you’re located in different places.

From https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-more-d5c28b91-7b9c-45be-8f0c-529bdbba019a says that uploading to the cloud would enable you to share it. You'd have to try whether it supports editing or not.

Upload the file to oneDrive and open it in the browser. Click File -> Share and give/deny edit access.

> [image: File menu]
>
> [image: Share popup]

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-a-OneNote-2016-for-Windows-notebook-with-other-people-d14b6033-7a95-4536-9216-bb0a5e0f8285

Also, Are you adamant about OneNote Notebook? Dropbox can do that. So can Google Docs.

Comment: Yes, I'm adament about using OneNote. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Can you add some stuff from the link? Because now this is not close from link only post (for example you did not mention cloud or any steps to share ).

Comment: Not  a regular MS user @Piro , iCloud FTW.